# ¿Cómo resolver el problema de undefined index con Ajax y Php?

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Muy buenas estimados!
Disculpen por mi pregunta, porque mi problema sigue insistiendo, he leído  detalladamente no sé cuántas veces al ***`controlcafe.php`*** y he hecho bien correctamente los códigos que relacionan bien al form, el primer error aparece así:

[image: Undefined Index]

Luego he pensado añadir en ***`controlcafe.php`*** dejando al final `var_dump($_POST)` y este es el segundo error para verificar los arrays del form:

[image: Arrays del form submit editar]

No logro comprender este problema, he estado estudiando y reaprendiendo una y otra vez al `Ajax`, he hecho formularios cortos y precisos, todos me funcionan bien con la conexión al base de datos. Este nunca, porque me pasa este error?

Dejo los códigos.

***`indexcafe.php`*** (El formulario)

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="es-ES" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="es-ES" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="es-ES">
<!--<![end-if]-->
<head>
<!-- Jquery -> Libs -->    
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Caracteres UTF-8 --> 
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Index Cafe</title><!-- 65 character (Limit 66 characters SEO) -->
<style type="text/css">
 table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
 }

 th, td {
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
 }

 tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  //boton añadir
  $(".anadir").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // obteniendo el id desde el boton.
   var id_compra_cafe = $(this).attr('data-id');

   // alert(id);

   // Valores añadidos.
   var id_cafe = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.id_cafe').val();
   var id_usuario = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.id_usuario').val();
   var precio = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.precio').val();
   var iva = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.iva').val();
   var total = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.total').val();

   $.post('control_cafe.php', {
    //variable caso anadir.
    Caso:'anadir',
    Id_compra_cafe:id_compra_cafe,
    Id_cafe:id_cafe,
    Id_usuario:id_usuario,
    Precio:precio,
    IVA:iva,
    Total:total
   },function(e){
    alert(e);
   });     
  });

  //boton editar
  $(".editar").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // obteniendo el id desde el boton.
   var id_compra_cafe = $(this).attr('data-id');
   // alert(id);

   // Valores modificados.
   var precio = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.precio').val();
   var iva = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.iva').val();
   var total = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.total').val();

  $.post('control_cafe.php', {
    //variable caso editar.
    Caso:'editar',
    Id_compra_cafe:id_compra_cafe,
    Precio:precio,
    IVA:iva,
    Total:total
   },function(e){
    alert(e);
   });     
  });

  // boton eliminar
  $(".eliminar").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // obteniendo el id desde el boton.
   var id_compra_cafe = $(this).attr('data-id');
   // alert (id);

   // Removiendo td tabla.
   $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();

   $.post('control_cafe.php', {
    // Variable caso eliminar.
    Caso:'eliminar',
    Id_compra_cafe:id_compra_cafe
   }, function(e){
    alert(e);
   });
  });

}); // fin documento.
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

require_once 'conexion2.php';

//Obtengo datos desde MySQL
$stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT * FROM compra_cafe");//Sentencia.
  
$stmt->execute(); //Ejecuta sentencia.
// verificando si hay algun problema.
if ($stmt) {

 $stmt->store_result();//Transfiere un conjunto de resulados de la última consulta.
} else {
 echo "hubo problema con la consulta";
}

if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
 echo "<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>
 <table><tr><th>Id_compra_cafe</th>
      <th>Id_cafe</th>
      <th>Id_usuario</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>IVA</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
   </tr>";
 // Obteniendo resultado desde la BD.
 $stmt->bind_result($id_compra_cafe,$id_cafe,$id_usuario,$precio,$iva,$total);
 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  echo "
   <tr>
    <td><input type=hidden class='myid' value='$id_compra_cafe'/> $id_compra_cafe </td>
    <td><input type=text class=id_cafe value='$id_cafe' placeholder='Id_cafe:'/></td>
    <td><input type=text class=id_usuario value='$id_usuario' placeholder='Id_usuario:'/></td>
    <td><input type=text class=precio value='$precio' placeholder='Precio:' /></td>
    <td><input type=text class=iva value='$iva' placeholder='IVA:' /></td>
    <td><input type=text class=total value='$total' placeholder='Total:' /></td>
    <td><button class=anadir data-id=$id_compra_cafe>
     Anadir</button></td>
    <td><button class=editar data-id=$id_compra_cafe>
     Editar</button></td>
    <td><button class=eliminar data-id=$id_compra_cafe>
     Eliminar</button></td>
   </tr>
  ";
 } $stmt->close(); // cerrar sentencia.

 echo "

   </table>
  </div>

 ";

} else {
 $stmt->close(); // cerrar sentencia.
 echo "<h3>No se ha encontrado ningun registro.</h3>";
}
$c->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**`controlcafe.php`**

```html
<?php 
$id_compra_cafe = $id_cafe = $id_usuario = $precio = $iva = $total = NULL;

if($_POST['Caso']=='anadir') {
 $id_compra_cafe = $_POST['id_compra_cafe'] ?: '';
 $id_cafe = $_POST['id_cafe'] ?: '';
 $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'] ?: '';
 $precio = $_POST['precio'] ?: '';
 $iva = $_POST['iva'] ?: '';
 $total = $_POST['total'] ?: '';
 require_once 'conexion2.php';
 $stmt = $c->prepare("INSERT INTO compra_cafe(id_compra_cafe, id_cafe, id_usuario, precio, iva, total) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
 $stmt->bind_param("iiisss", $id_compra_cafe, $id_cafe, $id_usuario, $precio, $iva, $total);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
 echo "Compra añadida existosa";
}

if ($_POST['Caso']=='editar') {
 // Obtener id desde el boton editar.
 $id_compra_cafe = $_POST['id_compra_cafe'] ?: '';
 $id_cafe = $_POST['id_cafe'] ?: '';
 $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'] ?: '';
 $precio = $_POST['precio'] ?: '';
 $iva = $_POST['iva'] ?: '';
 $total = $_POST['total'] ?: '';
 require_once 'conexion2.php';
 //Sentencia editar.
 $stmt = $c->prepare("UPDATE compra_cafe SET precio=?, iva=?, total=? WHERE id_compra_cafe=? AND id_cafe=? AND id_usuario=? LIMIT 1");
 $stmt->bind_param("sssiii",$precio,$iva,$total,$id_compra_cafe,$id_cafe,$id_usuario);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close(); // cierra sentencia.
 echo "La compra fue editada correctamente";
}

if ($_POST['Caso']=='eliminar') {
 // Obtener id desde el botón eliminar.
 $id_compra_cafe = $_POST['id_compra_cafe'] ?: '';
 require_once 'conexion2.php';
 // sentencia eliminar.
 $stmt = $c->prepare("DELETE FROM compra_cafe WHERE id_compra_cafe=?");
 $stmt->bind_param("i",$id_compra_cafe);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close(); // cierra sentencia.
 echo "Compra eliminada";
}
var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

**`conexion2.php`**

```html
<?php // estilo object orient mysqli
$server = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "cafe";

//creando conexión
$c = new mysqli($server, $usuario, $password, $db);

//revisando conexión
if ($c->connect_error) {
 die("Conexion fallada: " . $c->connect_error);
}

//Aplicar todo caracter al UTF-8 para MYSQL.
 if (!$c->set_charset("utf8")) {
     printf("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8: %s\n", $c->error);
     exit();
 }
?>
```

Aunque sé que es un formulario largo, lo practico para comprender cómo proceder antes de hacer otros formularios con los demás botones (sea insertar, eliminar y modificar) con varias tablas de bases de datos que he diseñado.
Espero sus respuestas y opiniones al respecto!
Saludos!

Comment: ¿Controlcafe.php o control_usuario.php? En el post de jQuery estás pasando Caso, Id, Nombre, Apellidos y Correo, luego en el PHP intentas leer id_compra_cafe, id_cafe, id_usuario... que no se enviaron por ninguna parte (y que es por lo que recibes el error). O bien no estás compartiendo el código que debes o bien no estás procesando lo que deberías estar procesando.

Comment: ah, me di cuenta, puse mal,voy a editar ahora

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ahora si esta editado, no me habia dado cuenta que dejaba un index equivocado (lo estaba estudiando sin percatarme de ello)  gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las mayúsculas y minúsculas son importantes cuando se envía información: no es lo mismo pasar un parámetro llamado `usuario` y otro `Usuario`. Serían parámetros distintos.

En tu caso estás pasando las variables:

```
Id_compra_cafe:id_compra_cafe,
Id_cafe:id_cafe,
Id_usuario:id_usuario,
Precio:precio,
IVA:iva,
Total:total
```

Con la primera letra en mayúsculas, pero luego en PHP estás intentando leer las variables en minúsculas:

```
$id_compra_cafe = $_POST['id_compra_cafe'] ?: '';
$id_cafe = $_POST['id_cafe'] ?: '';
$id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'] ?: '';
$precio = $_POST['precio'] ?: '';
$iva = $_POST['iva'] ?: '';
$total = $_POST['total'] ?: '';
```

Tienes que ser consistente porque los índices son "sensibles a la caja" (*case sensitive*) y si no están escritos exactamente igual no funcionará.

Por ejemplo, si envías `Id_compra_cafe`, luego tendrás que hacer `$_POST["Id_compra_cafe"]` y no `$_POST["id_compra_cafe"]` que sería incorrecto y te lanzará el error que estás recibiendo.

Comment: me sirvio tu respuesta, pero un problema, al testear, solo funciona con iva, precio, total y me preguntaba que pasaria si quisiera cambiar el id del cafe y del usuario en caso de que uno se equivoque? (me imagino que solo descartar Limit podría funcionar) y por último, me pregunto, en dónde puedo poner un espacio en blanco para añadir futuras compras?

Comment: Tendrías que hacer algo más que descartar el `limit`. Ahora mismo estás usando el id del café y usuario en el `where`, tendrías que moverlos a la zona de actualización (`set`) y puede que necesitaras otros cambios (pasar nuevo ID)... Y eso suponiendo que id_compra_cafe es el ID de la tabla y basta para seleccionar la fila. Haría falta más información

Comment: Perdone, aun no me acostumbro a los comentarios, id_compra_cafe si es llave primaria de la tabla `compra_cafe` mientras que `id_usuario`y `id_cafe` son llaves secundarias o sea foreign keys de otras tablas que tienen registros (con ids con sus respectivos nombres)

Comment: Se me ocurrió una idea más extraña, es poner unos textos antes del primer registro del id_compra_cafe y de ahi sería posible añadir los demás textos en el echo de `indexcafe.php` y dejar un solo botón de añadir, mientras que los demás registros se puedan consevar solo dos botones del editar y eliminar. me pregunto si se afectará en algo o debo crear otro control para ello? Espero su respuesta.

Comment: Al final, resolví el problema del botón añadir creando otro control sin problemas. Aunque tiene un ligero error, el mismo error que aparece del Undefined index: id_compra_cafe on line... aunque haya funcionado y logrado añadir al base de datos en phpmyadmin. Habría que cambiar algún codigo para evitar que aparezca ese error?